# select query to group items but also limit

Tags: mysql, sql

i am running this sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_billing a WHERE 

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer_billing b WHERE 
 a.producttype = 'VoIP Telephony' and 
 a.productname = 'VoIP Geographic Number (01/02)' and 
 a.customer_seq = b.customer_seq) 
 <= 1 order by customer_seq ASC
```

it should only show rows where `producttype = 'VoIP Telephony'` but  its showing others two

where producttype = 'Phone Lines' and more

Comment: Why are you doing the Count(*) <=1 comparison? A simple select would work.

Comment: This is the screwiest subquery in a where clause that I've think I've seen.   In english (not code), could you explain what this query is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer_billing cb
WHERE cb.producttype = 'VoIP Telephony' and 
      cb.productname = 'VoIP Geographic Number (01/02)' and
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM customer_billing cb2 
       WHERE cb2.producttype = cb.producttype and 
             cb2.productname = cb.productname and
             cb2.customer_seq = cb.customer_seq
     ) <= 1
order by customer_seq ASC;
```

Your version of the query is doing the comparisons *inside* the subquery.  So they only apply to the `count(*)` and not to the filtering of the entire query.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is selecting the customers that have only 1 line in the table that match the `producttype` and `productname` given. But the customers can have more lines.

One solution is simply to repeat those two conditions on the "outer" `SELECT`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM customer_billing a
  WHERE 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM customer_billing b
      WHERE 
        a.producttype = 'VoIP Telephony' AND 
        a.productname = 'VoIP Geographic Number (01/02)' AND
        a.customer_seq = b.customer_seq
  ) <= 1 AND 
  a.producttype = 'VoIP Telephony' AND
  a.productname = 'VoIP Geographic Number (01/02)'
  ORDERY BY customer_seq ASC
```